# mshtml.dll latest version for Internet Explorer 8, Windows XP Service Pack 3

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

Many applications in my system (Internet Explorer 8, Yahoo Messenger, Skype 10) are crashing and error details shows module name mshtml.dll. I checked the version of mshtml.dll in system32 folder. It is 8.0.6001.19170.

My Internet Explorer version is 8.0.6001.18702. I am not concerned about crash of IE, because I generally use Firefox, but how do I solve the crashes in other applications, which are due to mshtml.dll?

I have moved to Windows XP Service Pack 3 (32 bit). I have tried to update Internet Explorer 8 (from Tools->Windows Update), but again it crashes.

I can not migrate to IE 9, as it requires Vista or Windows 7. I have applied Cumulative Security update for IE8, which has this file name: IE8-WindowsXP-KB2618444-x86-ENU.exe

I could not get much info from Microsoft sites or Google. I do not want to use Automatic Updates feature of Windows.

Can somebody give the download links for mshtml.dll and any associated files, which I can replace in system32 folder?

Thanks.

Comment: *I do not want to use Automatic Updates feature of Windows.* Update manually... Alternatively, get the memory dump of the process and use WinDbg along with Microsoft's public symbols to get a better idea of where the crash is happening. [This article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-use-windbg-debugger-to-troubleshoot-a-blue-screen-of-death/) is applicable, don't get hung up on it being about a BSoD.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that simply replacing the DLL and any associated files (whichever those are) will fix things.

Try to reset IE first using the [**Reset** button](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16365/reset-all-internet-explorer-8-settings-to-fix-stability-problems/) (`Tools menu / Internet Options / Advanced tab`), or try this [MS Fix it utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737) and see if it helps.

Comment: Tried both the suggestions, but still same problem.

Comment: `There's no guarantee that simply replacing the DLL and any associated files (whichever those are) will fix things.` This is especially true for Microsoft products which are so deeply-integrated into the OS. Unlike most programs, and counter to the anti-trust rulings, IE and OE remain entangled in Windows instead of being standalone programs. (I particularly hate this because it makes it impossible to run OE in Vista+. `ಠ╭╮ಠ`)